# Is it possible to generate an HTML div with CSS ::after pseudo element

Tags: html, css, dom

This may be a stupid question, but I have to clarify this fact. So this is my concern. I can style two `div` elements to look like below.

```css
.element-container{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}
.element{
    z-index:1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
.element-shadow{
    z-index: -1;
    top: 10%;
    left: 4%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="element-container">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element-shadow"></div>
</div>
```

my question is can we do the same using ::after pseudo element. Basically can we add an html element after some other element rendered in to DOM (make the `shadow effect` after `element` is created, so someone does not need to concern about the actual size of the `element` when use it somewhere if the `shadow element` created with the same styles but with ::after pseudo element)

@Telary's answer is acceptable with this upper part of the question(original question) But now it directs me to another question, I was try to did the same with an `<button>`, but it does not work as expected. what did I miss here? Below code is my new problem

```css
.but{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    outline:none;
    border-radius: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid black;
    color: black;
    font-size: 250%;
    padding: 20px 100px;
}
.but:after{
    content:'';
    z-index: -1;
    top: 8%;
    left: 3%;
    border-radius: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(140,122,230,1);
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<button class="but">GO</button>
```

Is it because I removed the outer `<div>` element?

Comment: yes you can, just remember to add content attribute when you're using ::after element to make sure it will show correctly

Comment: your button :after element doesn't have width nor height attribute

Comment: you missed the dimension `width: 100%;
    height: 100%;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the code below to achieve the needed effect:

```css
   .element-container{
    display: flex;
    position:relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.element{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
.element:after{
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    top: 10%;
    left: 4%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="element-container">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

You need to remove z-index in ".element" selector, to put it on the top of "shadow" layer.

Comment: your answer is acceptable for this matter, but why does this isn't work with `<button>` element. I'll update the question